# how to use variables passed through header() in php

Tags: php, header

I'm using `header()` to pass var `user` from one page to another as:

```
header( "Location: temp.php? user = $user" );
```

The variable is getting passed and is shown on the URL of the other page.

I don't know how to use the var `user` in that page. Please help.

Comment: That's not passed "through the header", it's passed through the *URL*.

Answer (score 13):

page1.php

```
<?php
    $user = "batman";
    header("Location:temp.php?user=".$user);
    exit();
?>
```

temp.php?user=batman (you have just been redirected here)

```
<?php
    if($_GET){
        echo $_GET['user']; // print_r($_GET); //remember to add semicolon      
    }else{
      echo "Url has no user";
    }
?>
```

Or you could use a $_SESSION - but this could easily complicate things

page1.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user'] = "batman";
    header("Location:temp.php);
    exit();
?>
```

temp.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['user'];
    unset($_SESSION['user']); // remove it now we have used it
?>
```

Comment: Dont forget to choose an answer as the solution if our answers helped :)

Answer (score 7):

if the 'other page' is in PHP, you only need to:

```
$user=$_GET['user'];
```

EDIT: If you are not sure if you will receive 'user' and want to avoid error messages you should do:

```
if(isset($_GET['user'])){
    $user=$_GET['user'];
}else{
    //user was not passed, so print a error or just exit(0);
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this in 'temp.php' but it responded with
** Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\academic-education\temp.php on line 12 **
what do i do?
sorry m a newbie

Comment: If user is not defined in the url this error will occur. If you went to temp.php?user=batman then it wont error. Else if you just go to temp.php it will error. You could put an if statement around the echo to test if it exists before echoing to prevent this

Comment: Added a EDIT to my answer to give a example of how to control if the variable was passed.

Answer (score 4):

if you are using this to pass value

```
header( "Location:temp.php? user = $user" );
```

then on temp.php you have to use

```
$var=$_GET['user'];
```

to get the value and now $var contains the value you passed.

Comment: I tried doing this in 'temp.php' but it responded with ** Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\academic-education\temp.php on line 12 ** what do i do? sorry m a newbie

Comment: can you check this one in your temp.php.
print_r($_GET);
check if you are getting an array with the value of user in that array