# Using PHP, I am unable to get an Alert message to appear when a user logs in

Tags: php, html, alert

This PHP function executes when a user is successfully authenticated, when they are logged in they are brought to the page index.php. Perhaps I should have the alert message be in index.php itself rather than in the same php script document that performs the login?

I just noticed my success session variable, which makes the message itsself a bit redundant, but the alert isn't shown regardless.

```
elseif ($result > 0)
{
        $_SESSION ['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION ['permission'] = $permission;
        $_SESSION ['success'] = "You are now logged in";
    if ($permission == 3){
    echo '<script>alert("Welcome Admin!")</script>';
    }
    else 
    {
        echo '<script>alert("Welcome User!")</script>';
    }
        header ("location: index.php");
        exit();
    }
```

Update:

I have implemented the Answer suggestion, but I'm not properly grabbing the permission field because even when logged in as user "admin" ?user=User is the url. I have included additional lines from this file in case I'm making a mistake elsewhere that I'm not seeing.

edit: `if ($permissions == 3)` was missing an s, the URL is now proper, but no alert box.

index.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['username'])){
          $user = $_GET['username'];
    echo "<script>alert('Welcome ' + $user);</script>";
}
?>
```

submit.php

```
    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ? LIMIT 1");
    $query->bindParam(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
    $query->bindParam(2, $password, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(count((array)$result) == 0)
        {
        $_SESSION['errorMessage'] = true;
    exit();
        }
    
    elseif ($result > 0)
    {
            $permissions = $result['permissions'];
            $_SESSION ['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION ['permissions'] = $permissions;
            if ($permission == 3) 
            {
                header ("Location:index.php?user=Admin");
            } else {
                    header ("Location:index.php?user=User");
            }
```

Comment: Your `alert` doesn't function because you send it to the browser, then immediately change the page.

Comment: Note: header() won't work here, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php where it says Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent.

Comment: It will redirect if output_buffering is enabled - but it is messy programming.

Comment: Verify in url if the user=Admin exist ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to send the user or admin to the index page as bellow :

```
 elseif ($result > 0)
 {
        $_SESSION ['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION ['permission'] = $permission;
        $_SESSION ['success'] = "You are now logged in";
    if ($permission == 3){
        header ("location: index.php?user=Admin");
    }else {
        header ("location: index.php?user=User");
    }
```

So in your index.php you can get the user variable and show it in the alert:

```
$user   = $_GET['user'];
```

**To show Javascript message use this :**

```
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("Welcome '. $user. '")';
echo '</script>';
```

Comment: did you verify if url have this parameter

Comment: @syntaxerror take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266294/how-to-use-variables-passed-through-header-in-php

Comment: I moved my original comment to my question body, and I will take a look thank you

Comment: Try replacing your `header ("location: index.php?user=User");` by `header("Location:index.php?user=User");`

Comment: Thank you, the URLs are now properly formatted with login, but no alert is displayed.

Comment: Welcome to use javascript inside php see the edit : `echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("message successfully sent")';
echo '</script>';`

Comment: Thank you! This works just perfectly for my purposes now

Comment: This looks like an attempt to implement authorization - but without a lot of code duplication there is nothing to prevent someone going direct to the admin page.

Comment: this is just a php practice as you see, we attempt to implement nothing